# linux find command -- need to filter "no such file or directory" messages without redirecting stderr

Tags: linux, find, stderr, chown

Essentially I am trying to avoid having this happen without using the 2>/dev/null, is there a way? I would like the output of the chown -c i have linked to it.

ex: 
find / -user fred -exec chown -c joe {} \;

I would like this to output 
"changed ownership of '{filename}' from fred to joe"
chown -c provides for this functionality but I can't get the output if I have to redirect the whole thing to avoid find's errors!

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use process substitution:

```
find / -user fred -exec chown -c joe {} \; \
    2> >(grep -v 'no such file or directory' >&2)
```

`2>` redirects stderr; `>(...)` reads the redirected stderr, `grep -v` removes the unwanted lines, and `>&2` returns the remaining lines back to stderr